# IIS Application pool recycling settings

Tags: .net, iis-7

I have my website in production deployed on two servers on IIS.

Is it a good practice to keep different application pool recycling conditions of different server for the same application?  or

It would be better to go with the same settings?

Could someone please let me know the best practices with IIS automatic recycling, as i'm facing issue with system out of memory on my websites, many times.

Server 1: IIS application pool has been set to be recycled at 3:00 AM

Server 2: IIS application pool has been set to be recycled for every 1740 minutes.

Answer (score 1):

The best answer you can get is "It depends". 1740 minutes is the default application pool recycle time. I believe you should concentrate on getting the memory leak issue fixed for your application rather than depending on application pool recycle. It is more of a workaround than a solution. However, if you want to go ahead with it, set it to recycle during a time when the traffic is low.